# Better code suggestion?

Tags: php, oop

Can someone make my code nicer/easier? I think it's pretty bad coded right now.

I want to call a `INSERT MYSQLI` command function as following:

```
DatabaseHandler::__i('TABLENAME', array('username' => 'foobar', 'password' => 'world'));
```

I am using this now, but it doesn't work, and I think there is a better opportunity.

```
public function __i($table, $arr) { $c=$this->connection;
   foreach ( $arr as $name => $val):
      $param1.=$name . ",";
      $param2.="?,";
   endforeach;

   $PARAM1 = substr_replace($param1, '', -1);
   $PARAM2 = substr_replace($param2, '', -1);

   $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$PARAM1.') VALUES ('.$PARAM2.')';

   foreach ( $arr as $name => $val):
    if ( is_int($val)) :
         $param = 'i';
      endif;

      if ( is_string($val)) :
         $param = 's';
      endif;

      if ( is_double($val)) :
         $param = 'd';
      endif;
      $binds.=$param;
      $values.="'".$arr[$name]."',";

    endforeach;

    $values = substr_replace($values, '', -1);

   if ( $s = $c->prepare($query)):

      $args = $binds + $values;
      call_user_func_array(array($s, 'bind_param'), array($binds, $values));
      $s->execute();
      $s->close();
   endif;

}
```

Comment: you need to post this here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just an opinion, wouldn't it be easier to make the code "work" first and then try to optimise it? If you change your question to "it doesn't work", then we might be able to get it working first, and then jump with the working code to the link as @amitchhajer suggested

Comment: You should definitively try to pinpoint what exactly is not working first. What errors do you get?

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what's not working, **you should find out that yourself**, but I would write it something like this:

```
<?php

/**
 * Prepares and executes an 'INSERT' query
 * 
 * @param string $table
 * @param array $arr
 */
public function __i( $table, $arr ) {

    $c = $this -> connection;

    foreach ( $arr as $name => $val ) {
        $param1 .= $name . ",";
        $param2 .= "?,";
    }

    $PARAM1 = substr_replace( $param1, '', -1 );
    $PARAM2 = substr_replace( $param2, '', -1 );

    $query = 'INSERT INTO ' . $table . ' (' . $PARAM1 . ') VALUES (' . $PARAM2 . ')';

    foreach ( $arr as $name => $val ) {

        switch ( gettype( $val ) ) {
            case 'integer': $param = 'i'; break;
            case 'string': $param = 's'; break;
            case 'double': $param = 'd'; break;
        }

        $binds .= $param;
        $values .= "'" . $arr[$name] . "',";

    }

    $values = substr_replace( $values, '', -1 );

    if ( $s = $c -> prepare( $query ) ) {

        $args = $binds + $values;
        call_user_func_array( array( $s, 'bind_param' ), array( $binds, $values ) );
        $s -> execute();
        $s -> close();
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Getting this error: Warning: Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/classes/databasehandler.php on line 56 while trying calling __insert(array(
            'username' => 'testing', 
            'password' => 'hej123'
        ), 'users');